# nginx rewrite rule for two php parameters

Tags: regex, linux, apache, nginx, system-administration

Can you please help me to write rewrite rule for ngnix :

```
    Actual URL : http://www.example.com/all-dog-breeds.php?Greater-Swiss-Mountain-Dog/82



   expected URL : http://www.example.com/Greater-Swiss-Mountain-Dog/82
```

I tried below rewrite URL but it is not working:

```
   rewrite ^/([A-Za-z-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ /all-dog-breeds.php?$1/$2;

   rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /all-dog-breeds.php?$1/$2 last;
```

Comment: The first one should work if you remove the `^/` from the beginning.

Comment: As per your suggestion I tried but no success. I tried on        http://www.example.com/all-dog-breeds.php?Dachshund/9

Comment: Try `^www\.example\.com/([A-Za-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$`

Comment: No success. http://www.k9studfinder.com/all-dog-breeds.php?Dachshund/9

Comment: Judging from the answer that has been posted in the meantime, I was doing it the wrong way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're actually looking for is: https://regex101.com/r/uC1wH6/3

I believe that should be converted into Apache as follows:

```
rewrite ^\/[^\/]*\?(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: If all is successful I would appreciate if you accept by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.